# How do you effectively use gdb and IDA together?

Tags: ida, gdb

When dealing with linux binaries, I like IDA as my static analysis tool and gdb as my debugger. However I have not found an effective way to integrate the two with each other.

To give an example, let's say I want to place a breakpoint. I will find the place in IDA. Then I will switch from graph to text mode, copy the instruction's address, switch to another window where gdb is running, enter in "b *0x", paste, and then I have my breakpoint. If PIE is enabled the process is worse. This is cumbersome. Furthermore, when stepping in gdb I don't have all the names or comments I've declared in IDA.

Is there a better way to deal with this synchronization?

Comment: To be clear, I don't want to switch to IDA's own debugger instead

Comment: You can use the GDB debugger in IDA and use the GDB prompt from inside IDA if you feel more comfortable. This is the best option. Any other option, will be a hack or a workaround.

Comment: I don't mind a hack if it works.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1335.shtml and https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1343.shtml ?

Comment: @VitalyOsipov yes, see my comment below on the problem with this (or am I missing something?)

Comment: In that case, you will need to develop your own hack because of your own, uhm, reasons, by yourself. I don't think anybody was so "decided" not to use a thing just because.

Comment: @joxeankoret My preference for a specific debugger is well founded and not "just because". The reasons are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @joxeankoret he stated he prefers to use the gdb interface in his question, no need to be rude about it.

Comment: @TorbenB good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by joxeankoret, try using the "Remote GDB Debugger" backend in IDA. It's quite simple to setup, debug your program with `gdbserver` and connect to it with IDA.

Comment: @joxeankoret As I said, I want to use gdb, not IDA's own debugger. This link should show why they are different: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/can-i-send-gdb-command-from-ida-debugger-to-gdbserver  attaching to a gdbserver means I can't use the usual gdb commands, which is what I want.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I thought the gdb commandline in IDA worked in the same fashion as the WinDbg one. Unfortunately I don't have a solution in that case.